# Setup Particle gap between different particle systems

Tags: particles

I don't want an object to collide with each other. How do I set up to have a distance between 3 groups of particle?

[image]

Comment: If they are not supposed to be animated I strongly suggest Geometry Nodes for this.

Comment: Okay. thank for advice im just use blender for first time